# Set Parent variable from Child SetInterval function

Tags: javascript

Say I have a set of js that looks like this:

```
function a() {
this.meow = 0;
    var go = setTimeout(function() {
        this.parent.meow++;
    }, 500);
}

var woof = new a();
```

Why does `woof.meow` not increment and if I am referencing it wrong then why does this work:

```
(function() { 
   this.meow = 'woof'; 
   var go = setTimeout(function() {
      alert(this.parent.meow); 
   },500); 
   return true; 
})();
```

and even more confusingly then why doesn't this work:

```
(function() { 
   this.meow = 0; 
   var go = setTimeout(function() {
      alert(this.parent.meow++); 
   },500); 
   return true; 
})();
```

Comment: *"if I am referencing it wrong then why does this work"* It doesn't: http://jsbin.com/ufacor/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parent` has no special meaning in JavaScript (although it does on browsers). In your timeout function, `this` does not refer to your `a` instance, it refers to the `window` object. It happens that the `window` object has a property called `parent`, but that parent probably doesn't have a property called `meow`. The reason `this` is `window` in your timeout function is that in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by how functions are *called*, not where they're defined. See links below.

Since your timeout function is a closure over the context of the call to `new a`, you can do this:

```
function a() {
var self = this;

this.meow = 0;
    var go = setTimeout(function() {
        self.meow++;
    }, 500);
}
```

What that does is set a variable called `self` to the value of `this` within the call to `a`. The timeout function closes over `self` and so can use `self.meow`.

> if I am referencing it wrong then why does this work

The code you've quoted *doesn't* work ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ufacor/1)), but I suspect you saw something similar to it work because in that code, `this` references the `window` object, and it's pretty easy to end up calling a function such that `this` references `window`. So `meow` wold have ended up being a global variable (all properties you put on `window` are globals).

More on closures and `this` (on my blog):

- *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*
- *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*
- *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*

Comment: oh splendid okay, but then why am I able to reference `.parent.meow` at all?

Comment: RIGHT! okay sorry this was a bit of a brainfart I completely forgot about the variables being set to `window` haha oops

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder is right, alternative:

```
function a() {
    var meow = 0;
    var go = setTimeout(function() {
        meow++;
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: a() will remain a constructor, in this case, but meow will just be a private variable instead of a public one...

Comment: like I said, meow will be a private variable, if you want it to be public you can return it at the end of the constructor i.e. `function a() {var meow = 0; return {meow : meow};} var b = new a(); alert(b.meow);`